# Dynamic MySQLTable

Tags: mysql, database, stored-procedures, triggers, mysql-workbench

Here's my situation. I have 9 tables in my database which all have a c_no (int), a cl_no (int), and a status (boolean). I need to know the best way to create a dynamic table which distinctly shows the c_no, cl_no, and what table it comes from denoted as a number.

The difficult part is making it reactive or dynamic to all the status 1's.  Lets say someone updates one of the statuses we need that record to be removed. Also, if someone updates one of the cl_no to an new one we need that to be inserted into the table and if that cl_no for that c_no doesn't exist anymore from the origin table we need that removed as well. Basically we need an up-to-date table that consolidates all the info.

## Example:

**Table_One**

c_no,  cl_no,  status

1,1,1

1,2,1

1,1,1

1,1,1

1,1,0

**Table_Two**

c_no,  cl_no,  status

1,10,1

1,3,1

1,32,1

1,1,0

**Desired_Table**

c_no,cl_no,ref_table

1,1,1

1,2,1

1,32,2

1,3,2

1,10,2

**I have tried the following will without success,**

1.) Creating a view which ran at 50+ secs, we need it to return a result in under 1 seconds. With 9 joins, the query ran too long.

2.) Creating triggers for each table, but when importing or updating 10,000 records the response time exponentially increase to well over 2 minutes in test cases.

Sorry for the poor format. Thank you in advanced for your time and help!!

Comment: Maybe you could create a view with a union query. How would you choose which table to have as source if the values exists in both tables though?

Comment: The two tables given as your example data happen to be identical. Maybe you should demonstrate it with a different table2?

Comment: If the value exists in two tables we want them to show which table they have come from. I tried a union query and the run time was well over 50 seconds.

Comment: Definitely appreciate the input @cars10. I'lll update the tables!

Comment: jpw is right: create a view with a `union all` over all the tables and in each select statement include the table number as the last column.

Comment: @cars10 when preforming the union all query the runtime is over 50+ seconds, this doesn't work for our website as we need it to respond within 1 second.

Comment: This sounds like you are dealing with very large tables ... Can you somehow reduce the scope by using `where ...` in the individual select statements?

Comment: The queries were running slow due to non-indexed columns. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your looking for a union statement I think. Something along the lines of

```
SELECT c_no, cl_no, 1 FROM Table_One WHERE status = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT c_no, cl_no, 1 FROM Table_Two WHERE status = 1
```

If you then stick that into a view it will be dynamic and freely available. This does assume that your not needing to remove or deal with duplicates in any way between the two tables. The query would need to be changed slightly to manage that.

Your other option with the UNION is something like

```
SELECT c_no, cl_no, table_id FROM ( SELECT c_no, cl_no, 1 as table_id, status FROM Table_One UNION ALL SELECT c_no, cl_no, 1 as table_id, status FROM Table_Two ) lookup WHERE status = 1
```

Neither of these queries have been tested but should give you some ideas for options

What was your original query?

Comment: The queries were running slow due to non-indexed columns. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

```
select cno, clno, min(tno) from
( select cno, clno, 1 tno from tbl1 where status=1
  union all
  select cno, clno, 2 from tbl2 where status=1
  union all
  ...
) u group by cno,clno
```

Comment: The queries were running slow due to non-indexed columns. THANK YOU!